# Storybook - Cannot find module 'https'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, httprequest, storybook

I am unable to test a component in Storybook because it is throwing the following error: "Cannot find module 'https'." However, when I execute the same component with Next.js, I encounter no issues. I'm using React.

[image]

Here is the HTTP request code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import * as https from 'https';

const url = "http://localhost:5000"

export async function postAnalysisRequest(file: any, longPercentage: string, maxCorrectionPercentage: string){
    const req = {file: file, longPercentage: longPercentage, maxCorrectionPercentage: maxCorrectionPercentage}
    const response = await axios.post(url + '/api/analysis', req, {
        httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json'
        },
    });

    return response;
}
```

That function is called inside my Main component

```
export const Main = () => {
/...
    const anotherFunctionInsideMain = async () => {
        const data = await postAnalysisRequest(fileJson, longPercentage, maxCorrectionPercentage);
    }
.../
}
```

This is the story

```
import { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/react";
import { Main } from "../../components/Main/Main";

export default {
    title: "components/Main",
    component: Main ,
    argTypes: {},
} as Meta<typeof Main >;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof Main >;

export const Primary: Story = {
    render: () =>{
        return(<>
            <Main/>
        </>);
    } 
};
```

The HTTP request function is located inside the "pages" directory of my Next.js project

[image]

What could be the issue? I have tried several solutions recommended by Chat GPT, but the problem persists. I also haven't found any relevant information on Google.